# Getting the substring after a character in C# using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following input string:

```
string val = "[01/02/70]\nhello world ";
```

I want to get the all words after the last `]` character.

Example output for a sample string above:

```
\nhello world
```

Comment: Does it really need a regex? Just search for `]` in input and do a substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, use `Substring()` with `IndexOf`:

```
string val = val.Substring(val.IndexOf(']') + 1);
```

[image]

If you have multiple `]` symbols, and you want to get all the string after the last one, use `LastIndexOf`:

```
string val = "[01/02/70]\nhello [01/02/80] world ";
string val = val.Substring(val.LastIndexOf(']') + 1); // => " world "
```

If you are a fan of Regex, you might want to use a `Regex.Replace` like

```
string val = "[01/02/70]\nhello [01/02/80] world ";
val = Regex.Replace(val, @"^.*\]", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline); // => " world "
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E.*%5C%5D&i=%5B01%2F02%2F70%5D%5Cnhello%20%5B01%2F02%2F80%5D%20world%20&r=)

Notes on REGEX:

- `RegexOptions.Singleline` makes `.` match a linebreak
- `^` - matches beginning of string
- `.*` - matches 0 or more characters but as many as possible (greedy matching)
- `\]` - matches literal `]` (as it is a special regex metacharacter, it must be escaped).

Comment: What about my suggested patterns? I think my first one yields expected results for "[[01/02/70]]]nhello world ": "nhello world ".

Comment: Glad it worked. Please consider accepting the answer  if it worked for you (green tick on the left just below the down arrow).

Comment: I have added a link to the regex demo. The result of replacement is on the **Context** tab at the bottom of the RegexStorm page.

Comment: hey, sometimes input text i get like this- 01/02/2015 hello  world
without brackets, in this case how can i do conditional regex??

Comment: Then use [`^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%7b2%7d%2f%5cd%7b2%7d%2f%5cd%7b4%7d%5cs*&i=01%2f02%2f2015+hello+world++&r=) in the `Regex.Replace(str, regex, string.Empty);`.

Comment: i am using this one  @"^.*\]

Still have \n character with it

how to escape this \n

Comment: Do you mean you want to trim the result from whitespace? Use `@"^.*\]\s*"` .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lookbehind assertion. And not only that, you have to enable DOTALL modifier also, so that it would also match the newline character present inbetween.

```
"(?s)(?<=\\]).*"
```

`(?s)` - DOTALL modifier.

`(?<=\\])` - lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceeded by a close bracket

`.*` - Matches any chracater zero or more times.

or

```
"(?s)(?<=\\])[\\s\\S]*"
```

Try this if you don't want to match the following newline character.

```
@"(?<=\][\n\r]*).*"
```

Comment: thanks, can you please explain it.

in the same way like:
.

Match any character except newline

\w

Match any alphanumeric character

\s

Match any whitespace character

Comment: no need to match  newline character. i just need hello world.
i trying but result is printing in new line

Comment: thanks,
if it added multiple brackets then result want same
"[[01/02/70]]\]nhello world "

means it should extract from last ] char